# How to call data from 2 diferent table by id in eloquent?

Tags: database, laravel, firebase-realtime-database, eloquent, illuminate-container

thats the controller

```
public function hitung($request, $response, $args)

{  

    $datauser = User::with(['usia','aktivitas'])->find($args['id']);


    $tinggi         = $datauser['tinggi'];
    $berat          = $datauser['berat'];
    $nama           = $datauser['nama'];
    $umur           = $datauser['umur'];
    $aktivitas      = $datauser['aktivitaas_id'];
    $usia           = $datauser['usia_id'];
    $nilai          = $datauser->aktivitas->nilai;
    $energy         = $datauser->usia->energy;
    $protein        = $datauser->usia->protein;
    $lemak          = $datauser->usia->lemak;
    $karbohidrat    = $datauser->usia->karbohidrat;

    $amb = 655 + (9.6 * $berat) + (1.8 * $tinggi) - (4.7 * $umur);
    $amb = round($amb);

    $energytotal = $amb * $nilai + $energy;
    $energytotal = round($energytotal);
    $protein     = (15 * $energytotal / 100) + $protein;
    $protein = round($protein);
    $lemak       = (25 * $energytotal / 100) + $lemak;
    $lemak = round($lemak);
    $karbohidrat = ($energytotal - ($protein + $lemak)) + $karbohidrat;
    $karbohidrat= round($karbohidrat);

    return $response ->withJson([
            'Nama'  => $nama,
            'total_energy' => $energytotal , 
            'Protein'=> $protein,
            'lemak'=> $lemak,
            'Karbohidrat'=> $karbohidrat,
            ]);


}
```

thats the user model:

```
    <?php

namespace App\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model



{
    public   $timestamps  = false;

protected $fillable = ['username', 'password', 'nama', 'tinggi', 'berat', 'umur', 'usia_id', 'aktivitas_id'];

protected $table    = "users";

 public function usia()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Usia');
}

public function aktivitas()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Aktivitas');
}

    public function forum()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Forum');
    }

}
```

thats the aktivitas model:

```
        <?php

    namespace App\models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Aktivitas extends Model 

{

    protected $table    = "aktivitas";
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
}

}
```

thats the usia model ,

```
  <?php

namespace App\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Usia extends Model 
{
protected $table    = "usia";

public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }

}
```

this code is work in local , but when i hosting it , it didnt work , please need help for my exam ...

i think the problem is in this code ,

```
$datauser = User::with(['usia','aktivitas'])->find($args['id']);
```

any different way to do it ?

Comment: What is the values that would be in the `id`? have you tried to use where statement instead of the find() method eg. $datauser = `User::where('id', '=', $args['id'])->with(['usia','aktivitas'])->get();` ?

Comment: which error that you displayed on host?

Comment: i use post man , display blank page , and error is 500 internal server error

Answer (score 0):

I guess your local is Windows and remote host is Linux

first of all you should know windows file and folder name is not case sensitive and there is no different between Models and models in windows OS

but Linux file and directory name  is Case Sensitive

in your codes:

```
namespace App\models;
```

and

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
```

somewhere you use `Models` and `models`

you should check directory name and rename it anywhere you write wrong word

Comment: @YusranPanca happy, so you can check it as answer for your question